# How can I make an APK backup from an installed and configured XBMC?

Tags: backup, installation, apk, multiple-devices

I sell boxes with XBMC pre installed and preconfigured however it takes a long time to manually configure it with each add-on and then setup to my liking it.

I was wondering if it were possible to generate an APK from an installed XBMC. I've tried Titanium Backup but as XBMC stores in different places it doesn't seem to work.

It can be done as I've seen other boxes with preconfigured XBMC having a customised XBMC installation and they appear to be using ZipSigner on the Android Box itself.

Comment: I don't know how and where XBMC stores stuff. But if Titanium can't do it, there probably is no "automated" way. You might be able to "combine forces" by manually packing the other locations (and restore them *before* the Titanium-made backup). Have you tried that?

Comment: It's not it's storing, it's how it does it. For example, if I back it up and re install we still get the "Preparing first run" but it should be a mirror image of the other install.

Comment: That rather looks like some "first-run" flag being stored somewhere, but not "captured" by Titanium. You could try an alternative, e.g. backup/restore via ADB (or using [Helium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/helium-app-sync-and-backup/com.koushikdutta.backup), which does this on the device itself). Maybe results are different with that approach.